# Trigger function only if mouseenter event lasted 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a tooltip when a user hovers over a specific tag on my page. However, I want to do it only if the tag was hovered for at least a second. I tried the code below, but - obviously - `setTimeout()` will trigger after a second every time, even if the cursor is "long  gone".

Is there an easy way in jQuery to achieve this? Not really interested in any plugin-solution.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j21wjtwh/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="tag-tooltip" id="tooltip-1">Followers: 34</div>
<div class="tag js-tag" data-id="1">Star Wars (hover over me!)</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.js-tag', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).show();
    }, 2000);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.js-tag', function() {
    $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).hide();
});
```

**UPDATE ON SOLUTION**

Many good suggestions below, many ways to achieve same thing. I find `clearTimeout()` solution the cleanest, though. Thanks to everyone who contributed:)

Comment: in the function within the `setTimeout`, check to see if the mouse is still hovering `.js-tag` before showing the tooltip.

Comment: @lesssugar why don't you just use `.hover()`??

Comment: @ozil Will using `hover()` work with `setTimeout()` as I need it to?

Comment: Clear the timeout on mouseleave?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/cleartimeout-vs-flag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were almost there, here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/j21wjtwh/4/

```
var hoverTimer;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.js-tag', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).show();
    }, 1000);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.js-tag', function() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
    $('#tooltip-' + $(this).data('id')).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `flag`. Set it to `false` on `mouseleave`. In `mouseenter` check if variable is set.

```
var show = false; // Define var
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.js-tag', function () {
    show = true; // Set to `true`
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (show) { // Check if true
            $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).show();
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.js-tag', function () {
    $('#tooltip-' + $(this).data('id')).hide();
    show = false; // Unset 
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/j21wjtwh/2/

Comment: Flag solution always legit. Will work, I'm sure, however I was thinking whether there's any jQuery native way of doing it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tushar Wouldn't that be a better solution? You wouldn't even fire the function if the timeout were cleared.

Comment: @crush Giuseppe has already given answer, so I can't update my answer

Comment: http://jsperf.com/cleartimeout-vs-flag
clearTimeout is considerably more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.js-tag').on('mouseover', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if(!$this.data('timeout')) {
        $this.data('timeout', setTimeout(function() {
            $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).show();
        }, 2000);
    }
});

$('.js-tag').on('mouseout', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('timeout')) {
        clearTimeout($this.data('timeout'));
    }
    $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/j21wjtwh/3/)

Here is a Code

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.js-tag', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($('.js-tag').is(":hover"))
        {
            $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).show();
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.js-tag', function() {
    $('#tooltip-' + $(this).data('id')).hide();
});
```

But there is one small bug here, try to hover/unhover fast, and you will see it

**EDIT**
As for me [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30622139/2115584) answer much better. It doesn't contains my bug

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of whether or not you are currently hovering with a variable.
Set the hovering variable to true on mouse enter, and false on mouseleave.
Then in your setTimeout event, check if you are currently hovering.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/j21wjtwh/5/)

```
var hovering = false;
$('.js-tag').mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    hovering = true;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (hovering) {
            $('#tooltip-' + $this.data('id')).show();
        }
    }, 1000);
});

$('.js-tag').mouseleave(function () {
    hovering = false;
    $('#tooltip-' + $(this).data('id')).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store timer handle in variable and clear it using `clearTimeout` on `mouseleave`.
Here is jsfiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lz9snp9t/3/